# JAVA JPA between dates issue in query

Tags: java, jpa

Trying to use between in CriteriaQuery but keep getting compile issues!

Data is passed as parameter, see following code:

```
public List<PlanTacticBuyFile> getByTacticIdsDates(List<Integer> ids, Date startDate, Date endDate)
{
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<PlanTacticBuyFile> q = builder.createQuery(PlanTacticBuyFile.class);
    Root<PlanTacticBuyFile> c = q.from(PlanTacticBuyFile.class);
    ParameterExpression<Date> d = builder.parameter(Date.class);
    q.where(builder.and(c.get("tacticId").in(ids),
            builder.between(builder.literal(startDate), c.get("startDate"), c.get("endDate"))));
```

Getting compile error on the first param in the between call.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about parameterize your CriteriaQuery? I saw a date ParameterExpression object in your code, but I'm not sure if you have used it somewhere else.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<PlanTacticBuyFile> q = builder.createQuery(PlanTacticBuyFile.class);
Root<PlanTacticBuyFile> c = q.from(PlanTacticBuyFile.class);

ParameterExpression<Date> date = builder.parameter(Date.class, "startDate");
q.where(builder.and(c.get("tacticId").in(ids),
        builder.between(date, c.get("startDate"), c.get("endDate"))));
...

em.createQuery(q).setParameter("startDate", startDate).getResultList();
```

Comment: Yes, I could not figure out where do you make the connection between the parameters that is sent and the query! thanks for that!